# exe batch script to exe in powershel with parameters

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I got a batch script to automate some operations.
This code take a .osis.xml file and transform it in a Osis format ready to be read in some Bible progrs.

```
SET work=D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\osis\
osis2mod %work% - < cei1974.osis.xml
```

Now I'm tring to transform my batch script into a PS script. Here is what I'm doig till now:

```
#  $work variable contains the path of the folder with the original files.
$work = "D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\osis"

#  $bpc variable contains the path of destination of CONF files for BPBiblePortable
$bpc = "D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\BPBiblePortable\App\BPBible\resources\mods.d\"

#  $xic contains the path of destination of CONF files for xiphos
$xic = "C:\Users\Emanuele\AppData\Roaming\Sword\mods.d\"

#  $bpo contains the path of destination of OSIS files for BPBiblePortable
$bpo = "D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\BPBiblePortable\App\BPBible\resources\modules\texts\rawtext\"

#  $xio variablecontains the path of destination of OSIS files for xiphos.
$xio = "C:\Users\Emanuele\AppData\Roaming\Sword\modules\texts\rawtext\"

#  $Confile Array contains the names of .conf files. 
$Confile = @('cei1971.conf', 'cei1974.conf', 'cei2008.conf', 'tilc.conf', 'novav.conf')

foreach ($element in $Confile)
    {
        # The copy of the files goes well
        Copy-Item -Path $work\$element -Destination $bpc
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
        $count = 1
        $result = 0 
        While ($result -eq 0)
            {
                $result = $wshell.Popup("Copiato in $bpc",1,"$element",0)
                $count += 1
                Write-Host $count
                if($count -eq 10)
                    {
                        Exit
                    }
            }
        Copy-Item -Path $work\$element -Destination $xic
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
        $count = 1
        $result = 0 
        While ($result -eq 0)
            {
                $result = $wshell.Popup("Copiato in $xic",1,"$element",0)
                $count += 1
                Write-Host $count
                if($count -eq 10)
                    {
                        Exit
                    }
            }
    }
# The name of the .exe.    
$eseguibile = "osis2mod.exe"
#
# THIS IS THE COMMAND I'M NOT ABLE TO "translate" in PS
# The problem is that PS not recognize the "- <" passing
#
& $PSScriptRoot\$eseguibile --% $work\ - < $work\cei1974.osis.xml
```

Have someone find something like me?

Comment: `- < $work\cei1974.osis.xml` is not correct, is it? The syntax should be `osis2mod.exe <output/path> <osisDoc> [OPTIONS]`, where `<osisDoc>` can be either `the path to the validated OSIS document`, _(in this case, I'd assume `$work\cei1974.osis.xml`)_, or `-`, to read from standard input. I doubt therefore that you should be stipulating both!. You should probably just be using `$OsisDoc = "$work\cei1974.osis.xml"` then using `& $PSScriptRoot\$eseguibile $outFolder $OsisDoc`. I'd probably remove the trailing backward slash from `$outFolder = "$work\"` too.

Comment: You can use `$args` and it should pass the arguments properly

Comment: @Compo no as shown in the wiki: https://wiki.crosswire.org/Osis2mod, section called "Parameters and Options",`- < $work\cei1974.osis.xml` is the right way for <osisdoc>

Comment: @EmanueleTinari, are you saying that `$work\cei1974.osis.xml` is not a validated OSIS document? Either way, you seem to be treating `- < $work\cei1974.osis.xml` as a single string argument, and not an argument list. **`-`** is an option **`<`** is the redirector, and **`D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\osis\cei1974.osis.xml`** is the location of the redirected content.

Comment: @Compo sure, you're right! I give the PS instruction without `-` and without `<` and all is ok. Finally this is the terminal answer:
PS C:\Users\Emanuele> d:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\osis\CreaOsis.ps1
You are running osis2mod: $Rev: 2893 $
SUCCESS: D:\Documents\Downloads\Emule-Incoming\osis\osis2mod.exe: has finished its work and will now rest
PS C:\Users\Emanuele>
Tnx a lot, @Compo